# Is there a pseudopolynomial time algorithm for this subset sum variant?

Tags: dynamic-programming, subset-sum, pseudo-polynomial

The subset sum problem is: given a list of $n$ positive integers, and a positive number $T$, find a sub-list with largest sum that is at most $T$. The problem can be found in time polynomial in $n$ and $T$ by dynamic programming: for each integer between $1$ and $T$, record whether or not there is a subset with this sum.

Consider the variant in which the goal is to find a sub-list $L$ for which the sum $\sum_{x\in L} \sqrt{x}$ is largest subject to $\sum_{x\in L} \sqrt{x} \leq \sqrt{T}$.
Now, the dynamic programming approach does not work as before, since the partial sums are irrational. Note that the problem is still finite since there are $2^n$ sub-lists overall, and all lists and sub-lists are bounded integers.

Is it possible to solve the problem in pseudopolynomial time, e.g. $O(poly(n,T))$?

Comment: @KellyBundy the inputs to my problem are all integer numbers, so their size is bounded (in bits).

Comment: Suppose $f$ is computable. It is not decidable whether $f(x)>0$. It is not decidable whether $f(x)=0$. It looks like this question is not meaningful without further restriction on $f$.

Comment: @JohnL. For this question, let us assume that $f$ is the square-root function. I edited the question.

Comment: A related open problem is [*minimum nonzero difference between two sums of square roots of integers*](https://topp.openproblem.net/p33).

Comment: It is plausible that this problem is [sum-of-square-roots-hard](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/4053/sum-of-square-roots-hard-problems)